# jQuery class not being removed

Tags: jquery

I am using this jQuery snippet to show / hide content when a link is clicked..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    var selector = '#div' + jQuery(this).data('target');
    jQuery(selector).show();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7947/

For some reason the selected class is not being removed when another link is clicked on, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't you miss `.targetDiv { display:none}`

Comment: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/W4Km8/7948/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `a` links are not siblings, so the `.siblings()` call does not select the other links.

You should use (*for your html*)

```
jQuery(this).addClass('selected')
            .closest('.p_link')
            .siblings()
            .find('.showSingle')
            .removeClass('selected');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7951/

---

But this will still not work perfectly on your structure because it is not consistent. (*it will not work on the first link, because the `.p_link` is nested inside one more `div` than the others*)

An alternative (*for this adhoc structure*) could be

```
jQuery('.showSingle.selected').removeClass('selected');
jQUery(this).addClass('selected');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7950/

Comment: @tushar, the `.selected` are not the actual siblings. The `.selected` elements are deeper in the structure..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also by just two changes in your code:  Find the "closest" div of ".showSingle" class
1st change : Change first line of HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 p_link">

<a class="showSingle" data-target="1">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam iaculis orci id nulla aliquet fermentum. Suspendisse ultrices nulla id magna cursus blandit.
</a>

</div>

 <div class="col-md-4 p_link">
 <a class="showSingle" data-target="2">Sed feugiat fringilla lacus, quis aliquam turpis cursus eu. In dignissim ultrices tellus in convallis. Sed euismod tellus vel lorem</a>
</div>
```

2nd Change : 3rd line of js script code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
       jQuery(this).closest('div').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
var selector = '#div' + jQuery(this).data('target');
jQuery(selector).show();
 });
});
```